# php mcrypt and different servers

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

i'v got such code

```
function EnDeCrypt($text, $key, $s = 1){
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        switch ($s) {
            case '0':
                return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
                break;
            case '1':
                return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
                break;
            default:
                return FALSE;
                break;
        }
    }
```

if i call EnDeCrypt in one script, all works, if i try to pass encrypted data to different server in get param-i can't decrypt(get such string ŸTe³qëêyÀÝ)

key equals, result put throw urlencode\urldecode-don't decrypt

try to pass vector mcrypt_create_iv -nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decypher, you need to have the same initialization vector (`$iv`) that was used to cypher.

Pass it as a parameter to your function and all should be fine.

Comment: it's such i stupid crypting, with ones key it works, with another key don't wont encode-it's a terrible!

Comment: Think about the initialization vector as a part of the key.

Comment: The IV isn't part of the key.  The IV can be provided in the clear; the key obviously cannot.

Comment: Indeed, it is usually provided in the clear. I meant the "part of the key" as in "you need it to decypher" =)